# Updating React state based on what's in the database

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, postgresql

Hi I'm new to Node/React, and I'm creating a learning project. It's platform that connects freelancers with nonprofit companies. I would like users to click a button to connect to a company. Once this is clicked, the user will have that company added as a connection in the database, and the button will become disabled and remain disabled in future user sessions.

Right now adding the user<->company connection to the database is working, and the "connect" button is working. Once clicked, it become disabled like I wanted to. I have React state in place. The problem is once the user logs out and comes back in, and views a company he's already connected to, the "connect" button is available to be clicked again.

How do I change the React state based on what's in the database? How do I make it so that if the user is already connected to this one company from an older session, the 'connect' button will remain disabled? This is what I have so far (shortened):

**schema**

```
CREATE TABLE companies (
  company_handle VARCHAR(25) PRIMARY KEY,
  password TEXT NOT NULL,
  company_name TEXT NOT NULL,  
  num_employees INTEGER CHECK (num_employees > 0),  
);

CREATE TABLE users (
  username VARCHAR(25) PRIMARY KEY,
  password TEXT NOT NULL,  
  email TEXT NOT NULL CHECK (position('@' IN email) > 1),
  skill TEXT NOT NULL 
);

CREATE TABLE connections (
  username VARCHAR(25)
    REFERENCES users ON DELETE CASCADE,
  company_handle VARCHAR(25)
    REFERENCES companies ON DELETE CASCADE,
  PRIMARY KEY (username, company_handle)
);
```

**App.js**

```
function App() {

  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
  const [token, setToken] = useLocalStorage(TOKEN_LOCAL_STORAGE_ID);
  const [connectionHandles, setConnectionHandles] = useState(new Set([]));

  function hasConnectedToCompany(companyHandle) {
    return connectionHandles.has(companyHandle);
  }

  function connectToCompany(companyHandle) {
    if (hasConnectedToCompany(companyHandle)) return;
    VolunteerApi.connectToCompany(currentUser.username, companyHandle);
    setConnectionHandles(new Set([...connectionHandles, companyHandle]));
  }

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <UserContext.Provider value={{ currentUser, setCurrentUser, hasConnectedToCompany, connectToCompany }}>
        <div>
          <Navigation logout={logout} />
          <Routes loginUser={loginUser} signupUser={signupUser} loginCompany={loginCompany} signupCompany={signupCompany} />
        </div>
      </UserContext.Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

**CompanyDetail.js**

```
function CompanyDetail() {
  const { companyHandle } = useParams();
  const [company, setCompany] = useState(null);

  const { currentUser, hasConnectedToCompany, connectToCompany } = useContext(UserContext);
  const [connected, setConnected] = useState();
  const [formErrors, setFormErrors] = useState([]);

  React.useEffect(function updateConnectedStatus() {
    setConnected(hasConnectedToCompany(companyHandle));
  }, [companyHandle, hasConnectedToCompany]);

  useEffect(function getCompanyDetail() {
    async function getCompany() {
      setCompany(await VolunteerApi.getCurrentCompany(companyHandle));
    }
    getCompany();
  }, [companyHandle]);

  async function handleConnect(evt) {
    if (hasConnectedToCompany(companyHandle)) return;
    connectToCompany(companyHandle);
    setConnected(true);

    let connectUserInDb;
    try {
      connectUserInDb = await VolunteerApi.connectToCompany(currentUser.username, companyHandle);
    } catch (err) {
      setFormErrors(err);
      return;
    }
  }

  if (currentUser) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{company.companyName}</h1>
        <h4>{company.numEmployees}</h4>
        <button onClick={handleConnect} disabled={connected}> {connected ? "Connected" : "Connect"} </button>
      </div>
    );
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is make an API call after the user logs in to retrieve all the companies that a user is connected to from the database. Store the results in react state so your app will then be able to check whether or not the user has connected to this company before.